# How to import database without having .sql file?

Tags: mysql

I have removed Windows from my laptop and booted Ubuntu and want to import my databases from xampp. They are located on xampp folder but I don't have `.sql` files created for every table.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install xampp on your ubuntu (read this: 
[Install xampp on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904599/install-xampp-on-ubuntu-16-04)
) 
after that, move `data` folder from old xampp/mysql to new path.
now, you can use your xampp on ubuntu, or export and import your db by `command line` ([How to Back Up MySQL Databases From The Command Line](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-back-up-mysql-databases-from-the-command-line/)) or `phpmyadmin` to your mysql server

Answer (score 0):

You still need to export your databases to sql files from windows which you can then import into Ubuntu. The structure and information schemas of those database files inside Data directory are stored in internal database and so copying and pasting the data folder might corrupt them and render them unusable. In windows you can use command line to dump the databases `mysqldump -u username -p database > database.sql` then import the database in Ubuntu.